# Realm realmWithPath method crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, realm

When I call:

```
[RLMRealm realmWithPath:@"example.realm"]
```

It crashes and logs:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'open() failed: Operation not permitted'

How do I create a specific realm file besides using default.realm and [RLMRealm defaultRealm]? Am I missing something from the documentation?

Comment: Hi Tim from Realm here. Sorry about that! I don’t think we’ve seen this bug reported yet. I need a bit more details: Are you crashing on a device or in the simulator? Do you have disk space still available?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for helping me! I am testing this on my device, iPhone 6. I have disk space available. I have tried to call [RLMRealm realmWithPath:@"example.realm"] in my example app but it would crash the app. I assumed that the error meant that I had to first create the example.realm file in order to write to it but I thought realmWithPath would automatically do that for you.

Comment: I am using 0.85.0 and getting the framework via CocoaPods

Comment: It breaks in group_shared.hpp

#ifdef TIGHTDB_ENABLE_REPLICATION
inline SharedGroup::SharedGroup(Replication& repl):
    m_group(Group::shared_tag()),
    m_transactions_are_pinned(false)
{
    open(repl);
}
#endif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that this is the way to create a new realm file, and if you provide a full path to a writable location in the file system, it will work:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *customRealmPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example.realm"];
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:customRealmPath];
```

EDIT: Updated to a path that works on devices as well as the simulator

Comment: Thanks for the help Gusutafu! I tried this while running my app on my device and it still crashes with the same error.

Comment: Sorry about that. I saw you go help on github, but I update the answer for future reference.

Comment: This answer is correct. Please see https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/933 for more details.

Comment: This maybe will come in handy as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828851/migrating-multiple-realms-realm-version-greater-than-schema-version-exception/33828852#33828852

Answer (score 0):

See my answer https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4221

If you use realm file in bundle, it will crash in the device. Need to specify readonly

> readOnly: Whether the Realm is read-only (must be true for read-only
>   files).

```
let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mydata", withExtension: "realm")!
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: path, readOnly: true)
realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: But what if I want to write data, eg. from the widget extension?