# Migrating multiple realms - Realm Version Greater Than Schema Version exception

Tags: ios, realm

Why this exception is thrown (when I'm trying to migrate multiple realms)?

```
bool ObjectStore::is_schema_at_version(Group *group, uint64_t version) {
    uint64_t old_version = get_schema_version(group);
    if (old_version > version && old_version != NotVersioned) {
        throw ObjectStoreException(ObjectStoreException::Kind::RealmVersionGreaterThanSchemaVersion,
                                   {{"old_version", to_string(old_version)}, {"new_version", to_string(version)}});
    }
    return old_version != version;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I needed to instantiate realmconfig in the right way.

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *someOtherConfig = [[RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration] copy];
```

Instead of:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *someOtherConfig = [[RLMRealmConfiguration alloc] init];
```

And I needed to remove the additional schemaVersion config and redundant migrationblocks:

```
config.schemaVersion = migrationVersion;
```

Before performing the actual migration:

```
[RLMRealm migrateRealm:someOtherConfig];
```